# Encoded url is not redirecting properly in angular, how to route encoded url to proper address?

Tags: angular, angular7, urlencode, urldecode

how to redirect encoded special characters url to proper address?
in my project encoded url routing to web page.
i created route something like this

{ path: 'welcome/:id', component: WelcomeComponent },

actually i am passing url like 
http://localhost/welcome%3Fid%3D45
but this is not accepting
and it is accepting only 
http://localhost/welcome?id=45

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
{path: '**', component: 'NotFoundComponent'}

export class NotFoundComponent{
constructor(private router:Router,
          private route: ActivatedRoute,
          ) { 
            let url = this.router.url;
            url = url.replace(/%40/gi, '@')
            .replace(/%3A/gi, ':')
            .replace(/%24/gi, '$')
            .replace(/%2C/gi, ',')
            .replace(/%3B/gi, ';')
            .replace(/%2B/gi, '+')
            .replace(/%3D/gi, '=')
            .replace(/%3F/gi, '?')
            .replace(/%2F/gi, '/');
            if(url !== this.router.url){
                 this.router.navigate([url]);
              }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had same issue and mixed two previous answers:

1) Create a PageNotFoundComponent, and add route:

```
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

2) Detect possible changes decoding URL at constructor:

```
export class PageNotFoundComponent implements OnInit
{
    constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute)
    {
        const url = decodeURIComponent(this.router.url);

        if (url !== this.router.url)
        {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me and I believe, this is a nice way to handle the problem.

Comment: This worked for me and I believe, this is a nice way to handle the problem. I was trying to copy paste this - http://onestepahead.dev/home/show-cards?categories=1 in my browser address bar. But it was getting converted to - http://onestepahead.dev/home/show-cards%3Fcategories%3D1. This led to the route being rejected by my Angular App. The above solution worked flawlessly for me. There can be edge cases, but those can be taken care of. I was wondering if there are any alternate solutions as well ?!

Answer (score 2):

```
router.navigateByUrl()
```

You can use [`router.navigateByUrl()`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl) with absolute path to replace the [`router.navigate()`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) with relative URL.

[URL Encoding breaking angular 2 navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440887/url-encoding-breaking-angular-2-navigation)

Comment: What a simple and great answer!

Answer (score 0):

maybe use encodeURIComponent to send param, and decodeURIComponent to make it readable after receive

Comment: i updated my question. main issue is encoded url is not accepting... where should i need to user decodeURIComponent() this method and how?

Comment: url is building manually or by Router?

if manually ...?id=encodeURIComponent(value)

if Router this.router.navigate([path], { queryParams: { id: encodeURIComponent(value) } });

Comment: actually i am getting this url from other site redirection to my site... and i can't change that url, and i have to decode here @Damian Pioś

Comment: you can configure your router like
**{path: '\*\*', component: 'WelcomeComponent'}**
then in component subscribe to ActivatedRoute#url, and here you should get  'welcome%3Fid%3D45' transform it , decode and reroute to specific path.
**path: '\*\*' have to be at the end of config array**

Answer (score 0):

When defining a route like `{ path: 'welcome/:id', component: WelcomeComponent }`, you would usually call it like this in your browser: `/welcome/45`

The url you mentioned (`http://localhost/welcome?id=45`) instead uses a query paramter (id), not sure if this would be mapped to the same at all. The **?** of this URL must not be encoded, as it is some reserved character in URLs to indicate URL parameters.

If the system that generates those URLs actually gives you such faulty URLs (read from another comment here that those URLs are not generated by you), you have to manually decode the URL first.