# Angular navigate also encodes ? and = of the queryParams

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In Angular I navigate to a page and wants to give it a returnUrl as parameter. I do it in this way:

```
this.router.navigate(['/validation'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
```

But this causes the url to be:

```
https://myhost/myapp/validation%3FreturnUrl%3D%252FmyUrl
```

where I expected it to be

```
https://myhost/myapp/validation?returnUrl=%2FmyUrl
```

When I read the documentation, the URL should be encoded exactly as I expect: The values should be encoded, but ? be intact.

The wrongly encoded URL results in my app cannot find the /validation URL and sends the navigation to Angulars 404 handling.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Angular might be encoding the URL component, but you can use `decodeURIComponent` when you want to use it:

```js
const url = "https://myhost/myapp/validation%3FreturnUrl%3D%252FmyUrl";
const decodeURL = decodeURIComponent(url);
console.log(decodeURL)
```

Below code will get you the methods/properties to work on the URL i.e `URL.searchParams.get('returnUrl')`

```
 const URL = new URL(decodeURL);
 console.log(URL);
```

It will work as expected and get the parameter from it.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that Angular tries to go to a page named `validation%3FreturnUrl%3D%252FmyUrl` and not just `validation` due to this encoding. So I don't get the chance to decode it myself. My problem is that I needs to prevent this encoding in the first place.

Comment: In your case, when you are navigating to the another URL,  the current URL should not be encoded. Why don't you use `this.router.navigateByUrl(url); ` Try it? And there is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627078/encoded-url-is-not-redirecting-properly-in-angular-how-to-route-encoded-url-to) thread offers other solution too.

Comment: `navigateByUrl` is a workaround, but `navigate` by itself uses the internal routing and does not require the full URL. I am looking for a way to get rid of the double encoding so `navigate` behaves as it should. Multiple people has been developing on this app, so could someone have made some kind of custom encoder that does this behind my back?

Comment: I don't think that `navigateByUrl ` is not an work around , it is being provided by the angular routing module. There is something that might be causing URL to encode the URL because Angular doesn't do it by default.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My problem turned out to be, that the project has 2 CanActivate on certain routes. Each takes state.url and puts it into a returnUrl, which is how I ended with the double encoding. The solution was to instead set it to `route.queryParams['returnUrl'] || state.url` instead of just state.url . Then instead of stacking the URLs that must be visited, the last one wins and will be triggered by another CanActivate.
What helped me figure this out, was the comment: "Angular doesn't do it by default." - well, then we must do it.