# How to disable dynamically generated URL encoding on ` [routerLink]` in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have `[routerLink]` as below;

```
 <li *ngFor="let item of pageNumbers" class="page-item">
      <a
        class="page-link"
        [routerLink]="getPageUrl(item) | async"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        >{{ item }}</a
      >
    </li>
```

And `getPageUrl` method is like;

```
public getPageUrl(pageNumber: number): Observable<string> {
    const url: Observable<string> = this.route.url.pipe(
      map((segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
        let segmentsString = segments.join("/");
        let pageUrl = `/${segmentsString}?startIndex=${pageNumber}`;
        return pageUrl;
      })
    );
    return url;
  }
```

But on browser angular shows url like below;

```
http://localhost:3005/documents%3FstartIndex%3D1
```

desired:

```
http://localhost:3005/documents?startIndex=1
```

Am I missing something here? I would simply bind pagination directly to [routerLink], but there will be more query string parameters (filters, sorting) will get in to URL, that’s why I am trying to generate URL dynamically.

Comment: can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440887/url-encoding-breaking-angular-2-navigation)

Comment: URL you supplied mentions about `router.navigate()`. I don't want to handle that, I want my generated URL to be appeared non-encoded.

Comment: there is a answer about navigate by url check that

Comment: I don't want to navigate dynamically. I want URL to be appear once you mouse over the href, so people can bookmark it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the docs for [RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink):

- `[routerLink]` is used to pass what comes before the `?`, called "params".
- `[queryParams]` is used to pass what comes after the `?`, called "query params".

So, to solve your issue, a possible solution is to return an object from `getPageUrl` instead of a string, the object will have both the params and query params:

```js
public getPageUrl(pageNumber: number): Observable<string> {
    return this.route.url.pipe(
      map((segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
        return {params: segments, queryParams: {startIndex: pageNumber};
      })
    );
  }
```

and you use it like this:

```html
<a *ngIf="getPageUrl(item) | async as url"
   class="page-link"
   [routerLink]="url.params"
   [queryParams]="url.queryParams">{{ item }}</a
```

Notice you don't need to join the query segments with `/`, because `routerLink` accepts an array too.

Comment: I just noticed `queryParams` is the thing I need to use. Thanks for the helpful post.

Comment: You don't need to conouted the URL at all. Just pass `routerLink="."` and then the queryParams. Essentially no TS needed for this.

Comment: Also make sure to take a look at queryParamsHandling if you have other query parameters as well.

Comment: queryParamsHandling with merge promising, I did not notice that. Thanks!

Comment: what if we get url from an api and not the angular router? how should we parse it and split url/queryparams?