# angular - pasting a url with parameters in a browser always changes the special characters in the url

Tags: angular, url, routes, angular2-routing

I have a url link with parameters like this `http://localhost:4001/#/search?categoryIds=2,54`
but while pasting it on another tab, it gives me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJEJ2.png)

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'search%3FcategoryIds%3D2,54'
```

This always happens the first time I paste it on the address bar, but it works the 2nd time. The special characters like '?' and '=' are being converted to '%3F' and '%3D'. What am I doing wrong or how should I handle this issue?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? or in incognito mode?

Comment: Its probably due to using a url fragment in your route. Could be the browser that url encode everything after the `#` sign and hence you get a the encoded characters

Comment: @AleksandarZoric unfortunately, it is the same issue in other browsers and/or incognito.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `router.navigateByUrl()` with absolute path

[URL Encoding breaking angular 2 navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440887/url-encoding-breaking-angular-2-navigation)

Comment: So this is a search page with multiple filters and we want our users to share their links or urls with other users so that they don't have to copy every filter manually. That is why we are copy pasting the url directly into the address bar. I think we could have applied this if we were going to the link directly through the app itself.